# change page when audio time is ..... like 1.00 , 2.00,3.00

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In windows phone app, I am try get the event of time of the player.In my requirements i wants to slide the page when the audio track time is bla blaa. Is their any this type of event in **AudioPlaybackAgent** ? please let me know .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always set up internal timer that fires off every **x** ms and check the current position. If it is near certain points, change page. So you have to do it manually.

Comment: +1 = you are right that there is no such an event. I wouldn't only check the timer every x ms. Do it for example 10 seconds, and handle when playback stops/ends - then update timer (stop/start/adjust).